# Including angularjs into existing web forms project

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, webforms

I am trying to include angularjs framework into a existing web forms application. But I am not able to access the angular directives from the aspx pages. I am sure there is some part of settings that I am missing. I added the angularjs package using the nuget installer. It created a directory "Scripts" and dumped all the angularjs related files. Can any body help me in putting up the settings correct so that I can make use of angularjs directives on the apsx pages.

Thanks in advance for the help and suggestions.

Comment: Have you add a link to angular.js on your page? In other words, do you have it in your html cod?

Answer (score 0):

Include the script:

```
<script src="angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Add ngApp to the body tag:

```
<body ng-app="app">
    ...
</body>
```

In your script define your module:

```
<script>
     var app = angular.module('app',[]);
</script>
```